# Check that therapy is effective with FWER control

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have the following data: weights of 50 patient before consuming an anti-anorexia drug and after it. I need to check whether the therapy was effective, controlling FWER on given level.

I know how to control FWER if we have multiple hypothesis. But here I do not understand how to formulate them. I suppose that I need to check if means of two distributions (before/after) are the same, but how to use the information that these samples are not just weights, but weights of the same patients?

Comment: Does your data simply consist of (or be transformed into) two columns with weights, one the before weight and the other the after treatment weight? If so it sounds like you just need to do a paired t test

Comment: @RobertMontgomery yes, there are two columns. How do I control FWER using just t test?

Comment: Please see my response below, and you should edit your question rather than adding an answer that is an extension of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is known about weights distribution. So before using t-test it is needed to check whether the distributions are normal and have same dispersions. So we get 4 hypothesis:
1. X is normal
2. Y is normal
3. X and Y have same dispersions
4. The drug has no effect

We can use corresponding tests and write down their p-values and use Holm's procedure to control FWER.

Comment: No, you don't have 4 hypotheses you have 1 hypothesis. Your Null is that "the mean of X = the mean of Y" or something equivalent, your alternative is that the means do differ. You are conflating the concepts of assumptions of a test with hypotheses. To do a t-test you need to assume normality, this is something you can check graphically. If this assumption is not violated then use the paired t -test. You have absolutely no need to control the FWER, you only have 1 hypothesis test.